# Maximum number of disjoint clue-sets that determine the same Sudoku solution?

Tags: sudoku

"[Do sudoku answers always have a single minimal clue set?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/do-sudoku-answers-always-have-a-single-minimal-clue-set/85401#85401)"  **No.**  Solved Sudoku puzzles may have more than one set of [disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) clue-sets.  And those clue-sets can vary in difficulty, so one might be [easy](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm?bd=..3......4......2..8.12...6.........2...6...7...8.7.31.1.64.9..6.5..8...9.83...4.) and another [diabolical](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm?bd=...4..7....6.8.1..7....3.5.8.7.3...4..1.......6....2..3....5..8.4.9....2....1.6..), even though their 81-number answers are identical.

[*Gareth McCaughan* poses an interesting question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/do-sudoku-answers-always-have-a-single-minimal-clue-set/85401#comment248075_85399):

> I wonder what the maximum number of disjoint clue-sets that determine the same solution is. Obviously no bigger than `floor(81/17)=4`, given that 17 is the minimum number of clues to make a unique solution; I bet 3 is easy but 4 might be difficult or impossible. (On the handwavy grounds that 81 is nearly `5*17`, my guess is that 4 is possible.)

So, is it 2, 3, or 4?

Answer (score 11):

To start things off, here are three disjoint clue sets with the same solution.

```
. . . 1 9 . . . .      . 8 . . . 2 . 4 .      7 . 6 . . . 5 . 3
. 4 . . . 3 . . .      5 . 9 . 6 . 2 . 1      . . . 7 . . . 8 .
. . 1 . . 4 7 . .      3 . . . . . . 6 .      . 2 . 8 5 . . . 9
. . . . . . 6 . 8      . 3 . . 4 7 . 2 .      1 . 5 9 . . . . .
. 9 8 . . . . 7 .      2 . . . 3 5 1 . 4      . . . 6 . . . . .
. . . 2 . . . . .      . 6 7 . 8 . . . 5      4 . . . . 1 9 3 .
. . . . 7 9 . 1 .      . 5 2 4 . . 3 . .      8 . . . . . . . 6
. . 4 . 1 . . 5 .      9 . . . . 6 . . .      . 7 . 3 . . 8 . 2
6 . 3 5 . . 4 . .      . 1 . . . 8 . 9 7      . . . . 2 . . . .
```

[check 1](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/S/WebSudoku.dll?solutions&0,...19.....4...3.....1..47........6.8.98....7....2.........79.1...4.1..5.6.35..4..)
[check 2](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/S/WebSudoku.dll?solutions&0,.8...2.4.5.9.6.2.13......6..3..47.2.2...351.4.67.8...5.524..3..9....6....1...8.97)
[check 3](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/S/WebSudoku.dll?solutions&0,7.6...5.3...7...8..2.85...91.59........6.....4....193.8.......6.7.3..8.2....2....)

I think that finding four disjoint sets will be hard, since 20-clue sets are somewhat rare.

Comment: The difficultly ratings of the three are, from left to right:  [Moderate](https://www.thonky.com/sudoku/evaluate-sudoku?puzzlebox=...19.....4...3.....1..47........6.8.98....7....2.........79.1...4.1..5.6.35..4..), [Very Easy](https://www.thonky.com/sudoku/evaluate-sudoku?puzzlebox=.8...2.4.5.9.6.2.13......6..3..47.2.2...351.4.67.8...5.524..3..9....6....1...8.97), [Easy](https://www.thonky.com/sudoku/evaluate-sudoku?puzzlebox=7.6...5.3...7...8..2.85...91.59........6.....4....193.8.......6.7.3..8.2....2....).

Comment: I should add that the middle and right sets are probably not minimal. I simply took one (minimal) valid sudoku with 23 clues, and then split the other 81-23=58 clues into two valid sudokus.