# Is there a Sudoku answer that has only a single minimal clue set?

Tags: sudoku

[User *Abigail* comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/do-sudoku-answers-always-have-a-single-minimal-clue-set#comment248235_85398) on the titling of [*"Do sudoku answers **always** have a single minimal clue set?"*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/do-sudoku-answers-always-have-a-single-minimal-clue-set)
:

> I'd be surprised if there were a Sudoku which doesn't have at least 2 disjoint clue-sets.

Well then, **is** there a Sudoku answer that has only a single minimal clue set?

Comment: I think the definition of minimal is important here, you mean minimum number of clues, right?

Comment: @hexomino, Yes.  This avoids the large number of [container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Other_properties_of_inclusion) clue-sets that might be made by adding more clues.

Comment: Also, we could have disjoint clue-sets which are "minimal" in a set-theoretic sense (because they contain no subsets which provide unique solutions) but have different numbers of clues.

Comment: @hexomino, It sounds like that would be departing from the question, since the term *disjoint* implies two of something.

Comment: But basically, if you have two disjoint sets of clues which give the same unique solution and one has 18 clues and the other has 17, the one with 17 is minimal and the one with 18 is not (even if no subset of the 18 gives rise to a unique solution), that's correct?

Comment: @hexomino, Well by standard English usage, the adjective *single* (esp. led by *"only a"*) would usually be applied to the noun *clue-set*, not its minimality.  Particularly since there's context.  But if there's a better phrasing, please share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95390/discussion-between-hexomino-and-agc).