# Most objective online linkable sudoku grader?

Tags: sudoku, reference-request

A Sudoku's difficulty level is often the first thing readers notice about a puzzle.  For questions and answers showing a puzzle it would be nice to have a relatively objective linkable tester.

I've used [*Thonky.com*'s Sudoku Difficulty Estimator](https://www.thonky.com/sudoku/evaluate-sudoku) for this purpose, but [according to *user21820*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/do-sudoku-answers-always-have-a-single-minimal-clue-set#comment248236_85401) it seems *Thonky.com* tends to be an *over*estimator:

> The first one is not at all *"very, very difficult"*. I only needed basic techniques and a binary branch-point at G7 (either 4 or 9) to solve it.

A further check of the puzzle in question using [*SudokuWiki.Org*'s Grader](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm?bd=...4..7....6.8.1..7....3.5.8.7.3...4..1.......6....2..3....5..8.4.9....2....1.6..), (click on the orange *"Grader"* button), returns *"diabolical"*, which agrees with the presumed overestimate of *Thonky*.

Is there something that does a better job at grading sudokus out there online?  It should be:

- linkable
- no paywall or login
- include some form of sudoku shorthand in the URL

---

Failing that, if anyone knows of a good command-line utility that does the job?  Preferably a util that's already widely distributed, rather than something that needs compiling...

Comment: If you are good enough at programming, I can briefly describe how you can write a program that should be reasonably accurate at estimating how hard a sudoku puzzle will seem to a competent solver. I myself don't have the time to spend on this right now.

Comment: @user21820, Sure that'd be fine, but to avoid re-inventing the wheel please wait a few days to see if some other reader doesn't already know of something that meets the spec.

Comment: Roughly, use depth-first search while maintaining the number of possible digits that can go into each cell, at each step always filling in a cell with the minimum number of possibilities. But this doesn't find easy tactics, so if there are no 1-possibility cells, prune before each step by using a low-depth (say depth 3) complete search (without pruning) to find short contradictions to eliminate more possibilities. Measure difficulty by number of steps taken to find a solution (but excluding the steps taken during pruning).

Comment: This meta site should be used for things *pertaining to the site and/or its moderation*. This question is properly in scope for the main site, not the meta.  I'm migrating it accordingly.